# redirection without reloading the whole page

Tags: php

I have a framework and I think I'm following something like the MVC pattern: A framework (the model) an index page that controls the input (the controller) and the views pages (that are included inside main.php/the main html)

I read a lot about structure and logics, to write a good application. I read many comments like "Why are you outputting anything if all you are going to do is try and redirect the user to another page?". Well the answer is, the most common case: redirect after the user successfully logged in. Do I need to print something? Of course, the whole main page with a login form/post. How I'm supposed to do that redirection??

So I'm a bit confused about logics and structure of the application. How do you store all the output and do the header redirection without printing anything?

I was thinking about using javascript to do the redirection but I also read comments saying; "if you write good code (following a good logic/structre), you won't need to use hacks like javascript redirection". How is that even possible?

Because the php output_buffering should not be enabled.

I have the output_buffering enabled, and I can use header (after output) without any problem. If I use the javascript redirection the whole page reloads, but using header it just loads the content (the views content that are included in main.php).

So how do you do this without output_buffering?

Comment: You guys can keep down voting my question, but instead of hiding, you can come and tell everyone why it deserves it...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect to a success page AND pass messages - say, after a successful login - an easy solution is to use "flash" sessions, where you store a message in a `SESSION` and then, as soon as it's used, you discard it. You don't need to sore anything in the output buffer for this.

This is a very basic example, but should give you the gist of it.

**login.php**

```
if($login_successful) {

    // put your message in the session
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Login Successful';

    // redirect to the success page
    header('location: success.php');
}
```

**success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// check if $_SESSION['message'] exists
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {

    // print the message
    echo $_SESSION['message'];

    // clear the session
    $_SESSION['message'] = null;
}
```

Comment: But that header() will give an error: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent", right?

Comment: Only if you code it improperly. I process all form submissions at the TOP of the file before any HTML is output. That way I can do my redirects and not have any output errors, like what you're describing.

Comment: You mean before including main.php include a php where all form posts should be?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, all posts are at the top of the files, but since the files are included insde main.php in the middle of the body tags... But thanks anyways :)

Comment: You're most likely running into trouble with all your includes, and using multiple includes gets confusing and hard to manage.

Comment: there are not multiple includes, it's just 1 include based on the URI and comparing to an array it'll include one page or another.

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe you want to include the file on the success page?

Comment: What I needed was to have the header() before including main.php (that's when all the DOM output starts). But I just figured it out; moving the post script to index.php inside if url == /login include login_post.php. I think that's the most simple and clean solution. Same for logout; in index.php if url == /logout include logout.php (and maybe exit() or die() but since logout.php have header() it won't be necessary)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are mixing up some things here. What you are talking about are actually two different requests. Either the user wants to view the main page, or he wants to log in using that form on your main page. In your index.php you would have something like this (pseudocode):

```
if (isLoginRequest) {
   // user wants to log in
   if( validateLogin($loginFormData) ) {
       redirect('successful');
   } else {
       displayLoginError();
   }
} else {
   // user wants to view main page
   echo main.html
}
```

**Update** to answer the question in the comments: The better alternative would be to leave your form validation stuff in login.php and refer to that in your login form `<form action="login.php" ...`. Then in your login.php you would have something like this:

```
if (loginSuccessful) {
    redirect('success.php');
    // no need to call die() or whatever
} else {
    setFlashMessage('Login failed'); //  set a flash message like timgavin described
    redirect('index.php')
    // also no die() or whatever
}
```

index.php then is responsible to display your main page and, if set, rendering the flash message from a failed login attempt.

Comment: Sure! I'll move the login post from login.php to index.php. And no need to exit() or die() after header() right?

Comment: Yeah thanks! Adjusting my post script helped me find my desired solution.

Comment: But I can't leave it in login.php because it is being included in middle of main.php where there is output and the header won't work.

Comment: If you send the post request from your login form to login.php, you don't need to include it in main.php.

Comment: Sorry, I think you don't understand how my index works: index.php have an array with a list of valid urls and in main.php I compare the URI with that array, then the view page (login for example) is included. In login.php, like other page like register or change_pwd, I have the post request at the top and then the html form. What I'm about to do is to move the post request (that have header()) to another file, and include that file in index.php so that it won't give the headers already sent error.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Move the login post script from login.php to another file (login_post.php). The same for other scripts using header() after dom output. (no need to change the form action="")

In index.php:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
//some more security checks like esc_url() (non-php function)
if ($url == '/login') {
    include('header_pages/login_post.php');
}
// all these includes before including main.php
// where views pages are included and the DOM output starts
```

Since header() is inside the post script, no more headers already sent errors (And output_buffering off, of course).

Same for logout page that is currently being included inside main.php

Thanks to the other answers, they helped me finding this solution.